# creating an array the splits user input into 6 different textfields (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am new to Swift but I have managed to setup some code for an OTP authentication page but I need help recreating the code.

I want to have the textfields setup into an array and when I get a value (ex "123456") I want to split the numbers 6 ways and add 1 digit per textfield (1,2,3,4,5,6) and vice versa. How do I go about doing this?

Right now my code for my current setup is:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class PhoneAuthenticationViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Auth1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Auth2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Auth3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Auth4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Auth5: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Auth6: UITextField!

    @IBAction func textEditDidBegin(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print("textEditDidBegin has been pressed")

        if !(sender.text?.isEmpty)!{
            sender.selectAll(self)
            //buttonUnSelected()
        }else{
            print("Empty")
            sender.text = " "

        }
    }

    @IBAction func textEditChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        print("textEditChanged has been pressed")
        let count = sender.text?.count
        //
        if count == 1{
            switch sender {
            case Auth1:
                Auth2.becomeFirstResponder()
            case Auth2:
                Auth3.becomeFirstResponder()
            case Auth3:
                Auth4.becomeFirstResponder()
            case Auth4:
                Auth5.becomeFirstResponder()
            case Auth5:
                Auth6.becomeFirstResponder()
            case Auth6:
                Auth6.resignFirstResponder()
            default:
                print("default")
            }
        }
    }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Auth1.delegate = self
        Auth2.delegate = self
        Auth3.delegate = self
        Auth4.delegate = self
        Auth5.delegate = self
        Auth6.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        Auth1.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: A `String` in Swift is also a `Sequence`, meaning you can iterate over the characters as if it were an array

Answer (score 1):

Try this code if this helps you

```
import UIKit

/// Extension for String
extension String {
    /// Function which will split string in parts
    func splitInParts() -> [String]{
        /// Array
        var splittedArray = [String]()

        /// Split STring according to characters
        for char in self {
            /// Append character as string
            splittedArray.append(String(char))
        }

        /// Return
        return splittedArray
    }
}

class TwoScrollViewStack: UIViewController {

    /// OTP String
    var myString : String = "123456"

    /// Labels
    private var otp1 = UILabel()
    private var otp2 = UILabel()
    private var otp3 = UILabel()
    private var otp4 = UILabel()
    private var otp5 = UILabel()
    private var otp6 = UILabel()

    /// Label Array
    private var labelArray = [UILabel]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /// Assign Label in Array
        labelArray = [otp1,otp2,otp3,otp4,otp5,otp6]

        /// Get Splitted String
        let splittedStringArray = self.myString.splitInParts()

        /// Sssign Values to Labels
        for i in 0..<splittedStringArray.count {
            labelArray[i].text = splittedStringArray[i]
        }

        /// Check Output if necessary
        print(splittedStringArray)
        /// Output - ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in below code,

```
switch sender {
    case Auth1:
        // add your logic to append entered character into auth1 textfield.
        Auth1.text = sender.text ?? ""
        Auth2.becomeFirstResponder()
    ...
    // same in all case
    ...
    }
```